# Jmeter: Saving jsonextract value in an array object inside a Loop

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am new to jmeter and I am trying run http request 10 times to create 10 categories in a loop
[Creating loop to run http request within it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2e30.png)
[http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0PWy.png)

Every time, I store the response(category id) in Json Extractor in a loop.
[extract value from response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59d9c.png)

At the end of the loop, how can I store all the responses (i.e. category IDs) in an array object?

Answer (score 0):

[Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

Here is some form of Groovy solution:

```
def ids = vars.get('categoryIDs') ?: []

if (ids instanceof String) {
   ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(ids)
}

ids.add(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).id)

vars.put('categoryIDs', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(ids).toPrettyString())
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)